# Deedle frame save to csv file in millisecond

Tags: c#, deedle

I am trying to save a Deedle frame which contains a DateTime column to csv file. But in CSV file, the DateTime column does not contain the milisecond. I would like to save it with milisecond in format *[yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000]*. I tried converting DateTime to string before saving. It worked correctly but the performance is low. 
Is there any way to do it without converting to string?

Comment: Show us your code, it will be easier for us to provide some help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed accomplish this without needing to manually convert your dates.

The signature of the `SaveCsv` method allows you to specify as the last parameter a `CultureInfo` object. Internally, the Deedle code figures out if it's looking at a `DateTime` object when writing out to file, and if so, writes out that date by calling:

```
dt.ToString(cultureInfo)
```

where `cultureInfo` is either the object you pass in, or a default of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

All that is to say you can specify the date formatting by passing in a `CultureInfo` object with modified formatting. It's pretty straightforward:

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var dateformat = new DateTimeFormatInfo();  
dateformat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-mm-dd";
dateformat.LongTimePattern = "hh:mm:ss.fff";
culture.DateTimeFormat = dateformat;

myFrame.SaveCsv("SomePath.csv", new string[] { "rowKeyColumnName"}, default(char), culture);
```

Why I am specifically setting `LongTimePattern` and `ShortDatePattern` (as opposed to one of the several other pattern properties)?  If you look at the doc for `DateTime.ToString(IFormatProvider)`, you'll see the following:

> The value of the current DateTime object is formatted using the general
>   date and time format specifier ('G'), which formats output using the
>   short date pattern and the long time pattern.

Comment: It worked correctly. Many thanks to you. Besides, the `LongTimePattern` should be `"hh:mm:ss.fff"`